# Executable file didn't work correctly [Linux]

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface

I write a program on Qt C++ GUI, that from given user input generates three .cpp files with proper syntax (C++). When I start my program from Qt Creator directly or run it from console like a script its creates the files in executable directory correctly:

```
QDir().mkdir(QDir::currentPath() + "/Files");
QFile outputFile(QDir::currentPath() + "/Files/myFile.cpp");
```

When I double click executable file, the program starts and work fine, but It didn't create my files.

I am using Linux Debian Squeezy 6.0 and Qt Creator 4.6.3

Comment: You should use `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` instead of `QDir::currentPath()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when you double click on the executable files are created, but not at the desired directory as the current directory in that case is different. You should use `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` instead of `QDir::currentPath()`.

Comment: Note from docs:   *Warning: On Linux, this function will try to get the path from the /proc file system. If that fails, it assumes that argv[0] contains the absolute file name of the executable. The function also assumes that the current directory has not been changed by the application.*